# deserialize multi layer json object to c# object class

Tags: c#, json, variables, serialization, types

I'm trying to deserialize a json object into a c# object class. I checked how to read in a json file but I could only find examples for how to do this with a simple json but nothing about how to do it with a multi layer json like this:

```
{
    "user":
    {
        "inventory":
        {
            "slot1": "item1",
            "slot2": "item2",
        }
    }
}
```

invntory is not a simple string or int but another json object.
I couldn't even find out how a json object variable type is spelled in c# so that I can save the inventory object itself.

```
public object inventory;
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By Using This Site https://json2csharp.com/ To Convert JSON To C# Class

```
public class Inventory    {
  public string slot1 { get; set; } 
  public string slot2 { get; set; } 
}

public class User    {
  public Inventory inventory { get; set; } 
}

// Main Class
public class Root    {
  public User user { get; set; } 
}
```

Now Convert Your JSON To C# Class Object by Using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

```
// JSON 
string Json = "{'user': {'inventory': {'slot1': 'item1','slot2': 'item2'}}}";

// Desterilized Object 
var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(Json);
```

Comment: how do I use JsonConvert? I tried to import it but that didnt work.

Comment: add Newtonsoft Nugut in Your Project https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/